# C++ Intersect two maps on keys, keep value of first map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, intersection

I'm experiencing a problem with C++ and maps and intersection.

Have 3 maps, the first two being `map<int, double>`, and the last one being `map<int, CustomType>`.
I want to remove all instances of map keys from the first 2 maps, that do not exist as a key in the 3rd map.  In brief, I have the third map that contains a list of objects, and the first two maps that contain some data about the objects.  At some point in time the map with the objects is cleaned up and some items removed (user interaction) and now want to clean up the other two maps respectively.

I've tried the following:

```
map<int, double> map1, map2;
map<int, CustomType> map3;
for (auto it = map1.cbegin(); it != map1.cend(); )
{
    if ( map3.find(it->first) == map3.end() )
    {
        map2.erase(it);
        map1.erase(it++);
    }
    else ++it;
}
```

This gives me an error "pointer being freed was not allocated" on the map1.erase line.  I've looked into set_intersection but I don't believe it would work in this case since the values will be different.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate `map1` and `map2` independently. You cannot use an iterator of `map1` to manipulate another map (to `erase` from `map2` or to perform any other operations with `map2`).
So the code should be something like this:

```
map<int, double> map1, map2;
map<int, CustomType> map3;
for (auto it = map1.cbegin(); it != map1.cend(); )
{
    if ( map3.find(it->first) == map3.end() )
        it = map1.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}

for (auto it = map2.cbegin(); it != map2.cend(); )
{
    if ( map3.find(it->first) == map3.end() )
        it = map2.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Comment: Almost... but when you do `auto next = ++it;`, you've accidentally skipped over the first element in map1/2 and may now be on the `end()` element: if so `it->first` in `find` and the use of `it` in `erase` may crash and burn.

Comment: why var next? is totally useless and dangerous

Comment: @Velthune: in C++03 it was necessary to store an iterator to the next element before using erase, as the iterator you erased was invalidated afterwards and couldn't be incremented.  It's easier in C++11.

Comment: Your answer works (same as the other people below that said the same). The problem is using iterator of map1 on map2. Doubling the code works fine.  Agree with the variable next not being needed.

Comment: @Velthune, ok, I've rewritten without `next`. But why do you think the `next` is dangerous?

Answer (score 0):

You was close to the solution, but the problem is that an iterator is substantially a pointer.
So you can use "it" to remove both on map1 and map2.

```
void removeUnexist(const map<int, double>& m, const map<int, CustomType>::iterator& it) {
   i = m.find(it->first);
   if(i == m.end()) {
      m.erase(i);
   }
}

map<int, double> map1, map2;
map<int, CustomType> map3;

for (auto it = map3.cbegin(); it != map3.cend(); it++) {
   removeUnexist(map1, it);
   removeUnexist(map2, it);
}
```

Comment: Question says "remove all instances of map keys from the first 2 maps, that do not exist as a key in the 3rd map", but you're removing any keys from the 3rd map from the first 2 maps... totally different.

Comment: Yes, as you say "erase is called on map1 and map2" and that's what I meant by "you're removing any keys from the 3rd map from the first 2 maps" - but I should have said "...key *in* the 3rd map..." to avoid ambiguity, and even then it might have been confusing.  So, let me explain from scratch: you want to find keys in map1 and map2 that aren't in map3 - it's just impossible to do that by iterating map3 as you'll only see keys that are in map3.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to erase an element from map2 with an iterator from map1. That won't work. You need to get the key value from the iterator and use that to erase from map2. And when you called erase for map1 you invalidated your iterator, because you removed the element it was pointing to. Increment the iterator, then use the key value to call map1.erase().

Comment: "get the key value from the iterator and use that to erase from map2" - even that's not sufficient, because any keys that is only in map2 won't be erased.